# Getting started with SharePoint 2010 for SharePoint 2007 Developers

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Do you know some quick links that will help a SharePoint 2007 Developers to get started with SharePoint 2010.

Let me start with the links I know.

1. [General Information on SharePoint 2010](http://blog.ksenthil.net/archive/2009/11/06/sharepoint-2010-ndash-resources.aspx)
2. [Must watch videos for SharePoint 2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/SharePoint2010Developer/)

Comment: Way to snag the low-hanging SharePoint 2010 fruit!

Comment: What about waiting a matter of days until the public Beta and inevitable avalanche of info? ;)

Comment: Do you the date Ryan ? I read it somewhere its on 18th

Comment: it's may 12. (http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2010/04/16/sharepoint-2010-reaches-rtm.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joris Poelmans has linked to most of the resources on his blog. If you want to be get up to speed fast and you are a Microsoft Partner, try to go for a SharePoint 2010 Ignite training, gets you up to speed real fast.

http://jopx.blogspot.com/2009/11/sharepoint-server-2010-getting-started.html

Answer (score 3):

The SharePoint Developer Center has some great content as well.

[SharePoint general development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Not just for SharePoint 2007 developers, but i guess a good start is to setup a development machine:
[How to Build a SharePoint 2010 Development Machine](http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2009/10/29/how-to-build-a-sharepoint-2010-development-machine-part-i.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of events, especially after the recent SharePoint conference.

One of the ones I heard about last night is [SharePoint Saturday](http://www.sharepointsaturday.org/). It's free and it's offered in a number of cities.

Answer (score 1):

This site has previews of new SP 2010 features and how VS 2010 makes it easier to create SP apps:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/2010/SNEAK_PEEK/Pages/Developer-Video.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have written a range of blog posts about [moving a WSPBuilder solution from SharePoint 2007 to 2010](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2010/03/porting-sharepoint-2007-wspbuilder.html).

Quite insightful if you have experience with SharePoint 2007 development.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of new features in the Business Data Catalog.  The team has been posting lots of new articles about these enhancements to their blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/bcs/